# Maximum Likelihood with Eigen (C++)

Tags: optimization, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to calibrate a magnetometer using the approach found [here](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:573843/FULLTEXT01.pdf) using an Arduino via the Eigen library. The main issue is that I'm not sure how to solve the maximum likelihood equation (see eq. 14).

I can do it in Python using [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), but I can't find an Eigen analog - How can I solve this?

Comment: There are some optimizers in the [unsupported](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/index.html) modules but YMMV regarding their quality. You can also use Eigen to implement the cost and gradient functions for another optimization library such as [Ceres](http://ceres-solver.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Eigen is for linear algebra. It does not contain optimization routines afaik. So either write the optimization function yourself or use a different library.

Comment: There are some (unsupported) Non-linear optimization methods here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__NonLinearOptimization__Module.html and Levenberg-Marquardt is again implemented here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__LevenbergMarquardt__Module.html (I can't say much about the state of these modules ...)